# DotNet.Highcharts adding another series

Tags: .net, highcharts

Let's say i've created chart and i'm trying to add another series to it.

I have the following code for setting first series. It's a WebMethod which returns string and it works just fine:

```
  .SetSeries(new Series
        {

          Data = new Data(new object[] {FrequencyAnalysisWS.Calculate(TextBox1.Text)})

        })
```

but what i can't figure out is how to add another series next to this one.

So far it looks like this: http://postimage.org/image/8ydmck507/

But i want something like this(two columns for every letter): http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

Thanks for help :))

Comment: Don't really know .NET, but look at the source of the demo. Basically you'll want to define letters as categories and have multiple data objects.